# How to get the distance between two SKSpriteNode objects for use in Potential Fields algorithm?

Tags: ios, swift, artificial-intelligence

First off as a disclaimer, I am perfectly aware that the SpriteKit Physics bodies are capable of collecting collisions. This is not what I'm trying to do. I'm attempting to build a potential field AI and to do that part of the calculations for the attraction and repel vectors require the distance between two objects.

Finding the distance I thought would be simply using the distance formula, but for some reason I'm getting very wonky results for my distances, so I'd like to consult if someone can catch what I'm doing wrong.

Below I use a simple distance formula with the points positions aligned to their centers.

```
func getDistanceBetweenTwoObjects(sourceNode:SKSpriteNode, destinationNode:SKSpriteNode) -> CGFloat{
    var centerSourceNode = CGPoint(x: sourceNode.position.x, y: sourceNode.position.y)
    centerSourceNode.x += sourceNode.size.width/2
    centerSourceNode.y += sourceNode.size.width/2

    var centerDestNode = CGPoint(x: destinationNode.position.x, y: destinationNode.position.y)
    centerDestNode.x += destinationNode.size.width/2
    centerDestNode.y += destinationNode.size.width/2
    var distance = sqrt(pow((centerSourceNode.x - centerDestNode.x), 2) + pow((centerSourceNode.y - centerDestNode.y), 2))
    return distance
}
```

Here is the function I use to create an attraction vector.

```
func getAttractionVector(node:SKSpriteNode, destinationNode:SKSpriteNode, spread:CGFloat, strength:CGFloat) -> (xSpeed: CGFloat, ySpeed: CGFloat){
    var sourceNodeRadius = sqrt(pow(node.size.width/2,2))
    var destNodeRadius = sqrt(pow(destinationNode.size.width/2,2))
    var radius = sourceNodeRadius + destNodeRadius
    var distance = getDistanceBetweenTwoObjects(node, destinationNode: destinationNode)
    if distance < radius{
        return (0,0)
    }
    var angle = atan((destinationNode.position.y - node.position.y)/(destinationNode.position.x - node.position.x))
    var xSpeed:CGFloat = 0
    var ySpeed:CGFloat = 0

    if radius <= distance && distance <= spread + radius{
        xSpeed = strength * (distance - radius) * cos(angle)
        ySpeed = strength * (distance - radius) * sin(angle)
    }else if distance > spread + radius{
        xSpeed = strength * spread * cos(angle)
        ySpeed = strength * spread * sin(angle)
    }
    return (xSpeed, ySpeed)
}
```

I use a similar math to do the repel vector:

```
    func getRepelVector(node:SKSpriteNode, destinationNode:SKSpriteNode, spread:CGFloat, strength:CGFloat) -> (xSpeed: CGFloat, ySpeed: CGFloat){

    var sourceNodeRadius = sqrt(pow(node.size.width/2,2))
    var destNodeRadius = sqrt(pow(destinationNode.size.width/2,2))
    var radius = sourceNodeRadius + destNodeRadius
    var distance = getDistanceBetweenTwoObjects(node, destinationNode: destinationNode)
    if distance > spread + radius{
        return (0,0)
    }

    var angle = atan((destinationNode.position.y - node.position.y)/(destinationNode.position.x - node.position.x))
    var xSpeed:CGFloat = 0
    var ySpeed:CGFloat = 0
    println("\(distance) : \(radius)")
    if radius <= distance && distance <= spread + radius{
        xSpeed = strength * (spread + radius - distance) * cos(angle)
        ySpeed = strength * (spread + radius - distance) * sin(angle)
    }else if distance < radius{
        xSpeed = getSign(cos(angle)) * CGFloat.max
        ySpeed = getSign(sin(angle)) * CGFloat.max
        println("HERE")
    }
    return (xSpeed, ySpeed)
}
```

Unfortunately, the distance formula is clearly failing me, I've caught the node at multiple times either touching and it not picking it up, or not touching, and thinking its touching. Can anyone see where I'm doing this wrong or suggest a simpler way to accurately calculating distance between two SpriteNodes? Hope its something simple. Thanks.

The following image shows my AINode solving my maze (orange), an obstacle to avoid (blue) and my goal (green).

The AINode has a width of 20 in this example.
The obstacle has a width of 50 in this example.

With the debugger paused in this invalid state where the AINode has illegally intersected the obstacle, the distance between the center points using the formulas supplied above is reading "28.28". The real distance is 7. 
[image]

**UPDATE**

I've caught a major error in my attraction and repel vectors that was augmenting the problem. My distance formula was a little off, but it was magnified due to an error in how I calculate the angle. The angle needs to be calculated with `atan2` not `atan`. The reason being is that the angle will be returned in the incorrect quadrant if `atan2` is not used, this distorted the direction of the repel vectors and caused major errors.

Comment: Your distance function indicates that your nodes have an anchorPoint of (0,0) rather than the default (0.5, 0.5) could this be the cause of your troubles? If it is you can actually reduce that function to a one-liner, or better yet make it an extension of CGPoint...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Larry might be on to something, as your use of `centerSourceNode.x += sourceNode.size.width/2` indicates that your nodes have an anchorPoint of (0,0) rather than the default (0.5, 0.5).

With the default value the position of the sprite is the position of its *center* in the parent-node, meaning you don't need to consider anything but the two nodes' positions.

As I mentioned in my comment this also leads us to the rather neat possibility of solving it with an extension to CGPoint:

```
extension CGPoint {
    func distanceFromCGPoint(point:CGPoint)->CGFloat{
        return sqrt(pow(self.x - point.x,2) + pow(self.y - point.y,2))
    }
}
```

Then, wherever you need this you can get the distance with a simple call to this:

`let distance = spriteA.position.distanceFromCGPoint(spriteB.position)`

Comment: The anchor-points for the objects are on 0.5, 0.5, therefore I do not need to offset the position to the middle. That was one of my questions about spritekit. If I understand correctly, the position of the object changes if you change the anchorpoint? ie: if anchor point is 0.5, 0.5, position will be the center of the object, if anchor point is 0, 0, position will be bottom left. Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

You incorrectly use `size.width` when calculating the vertical center point of your nodes. (That is: `centerSourceNode.y += sourceNode.size.width/2` should be `sourceNode.size.height/2` and same with `centerDestNode`)

At a higher level, have you taken a look at the new `UIFieldBehavior` types in iOS 9 and, for path-finding, Gameplay Kit?

Comment: +1 I'll look up UIFieldBehavior, that seems quite interesting. As for the width, since i'm using squares width=height, so why would that make an impact?